# WSO2IS - Broken after changing the hostname

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We were forced to change the hostname of the WSO2IS from sso.domain.com to sso1.domain.com for reasons I could not avoid. I proceeded to manually update all of the configuration files to reflect the change. It also shows correctly inside of the carbon admin panel. I cannot log into the user dashboard. I also get the below java error in the  wso2carbon.log:

```
java.io.IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: sso1.domain.com
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:163)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sso1.domain.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:743)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
... 44 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-27 11:32:04,079] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/authenticationendpoint] threw exception 
java.io.IOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: sso1.domain.com
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:163)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sso1.domain.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:743)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue all stemmed from a malformed DNS entry. Once this was corrected and DNS flushed in the environment the java error corrected and the dashboard became accessible.